# Summing distinct number of elements attached to an index

Tags: sql, count, distinct, aggregate-functions

Given a relation:

```
-----
|x|y|
-----
|1|0|
|1|1|
|1|2|
|1|3|
|2|5|
|2|6|
-----
```

turns into

```
-----
|x|z|
-----
|1|4|
|2|2|
-----
```

where z counts the distinct entries for the index x in sql?

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct entries"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
select x, count(distinct y) z
from mytable
group by x
```

I added `distinct` based on the description of your question, but your sample data does not discriminates whether you actually need it (there are no duplicate values in `y`). `count(*)` would work just as fine here.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to SQL didn't know the group by operator existed!